# Using ecryptfs "the other way around"?

Tags: ecryptfs

If I have two folders E en D and a passphrase P, in a typical ecryptfs setup I would something like this:

- I setup folder E to be the encrypted version of folder D, using passphrase P to do the encryption/decryption.
- Folder E stores the actual data to disk, encrypted.
- Folder D is my live interface as a user, representing the data to me, decrypted on the fly.

But, can I also use this the other way around?

- I still set up folder E as the encrypted version of folder D, using passphrase P as the key for encryption.
- However, I interact directly using folder E. Folder E contains from my perspective as a user, my regular "decrypted" data.
- Folder D considers E as being encrypted, and represents a live view of that data "decrypted" using passphrase P, actually encrypting it in the process.
- I would be able to use folder D as the primary source for a backup of my data in folder E to a public cloud provider.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't get that point: *However, I interact directly using folder E. Folder E contains from my perspective as a user, my regular "decrypted" data.*. Why would you want to do that instead of just using D ?

Comment: Because this is perfectly possible as it's now: *I would be able to use folder D as the primary source for a backup of my data in folder E to a public cloud provider.*

Comment: The reason is I am replicating this data on the LAN, and any scenario where the decrypted folder would not be mounted could have severe consequences. What I propose would be far more robust from that point of view.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could test ecryptfs does not support a feature as encfs does: [Filesystem that gives an encrypted view of a directory—the inverse of EncFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193891/filesystem-that-gives-an-encrypted-view-of-a-directory-the-inverse-of-encfs) still seems to be the way to go.

I wanted to "avoid" encfs because of some security fuzz around it, but I assume it is better than plain data anyway.

Comment: I read the audit of EncFS and some issues were fairly common to any encryption (attacker with repeated rw access could be trouble), or should tweak a few things (64-bit's too small),  and non-standard things. But editing the config file & inserting holes undetected are concerning. But keeping a secure copy of the config file &/or a hash of all encrypted files should detect tampering... It all really depends on your threat model, EncFS may not protect against a government or big corp., but should be great against siblings & common thieves. Or just add a LUKS file for life-critical data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the added space of an encrypted backup folder just using eCryptfs, you might want to look into [CryFS](https://www.cryfs.org).

It seems to be designed with cloud storage in mind, attempting to hide all file & directory metadata. [Sounds similar](https://www.cryfs.org/howitworks) to taking a LUKS container and storing each individual block as a file (but probably using clumps of blocks, to avoid millions of 512-byte files).

It's in the [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=cryfs) (Stretch/Stable[9], Buster/Testing[10], Sid) & [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cryfs&searchon=names) (Zesty[17.04], Artful[17.10] & Bionic[18.04]) repositories, while their webpage has downloads for some older versions.

I'm not 100% sure if it supports the `--reverse` view of EncFS you seem to be indirectly looking for, but the could software I found for linux all makes a local copy of the cloud files anyway, so again you'd have an encrypted "backup" folder.